# Why can I not create variables in a GNU make 'define' directive

Tags: android, makefile, gnu-make, recipe

I'm trying to build a GNU Make [Canned Recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canned-Recipes.html), like so:

```
define this-will-fail
my_var=1
$(info your variable is $(my_var))
endef

$(this-will-fail)
```

This causes an error `*** missing separator. Stop.`

However, the following works as expected:

```
define why-does-this-work
$(eval my_var=1)
$(info your variable is $(my_var))
endef

$(why-does-this-work)
```

by printing `your variable is 1`.

I'm looking at [AOSP's build system](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/definitions.mk) and frequently see usage of `eval` paired with `define`. What's the relationship between these two items, and why can I not create variables "normally" when using `define`?

Comment: The canned recipe documentation that you link to talks about _shell_ snippets, not Make ones (in fact, the very word "recipe" in Make context always means "the shell code part of a rule").

Comment: @MichaelLivshin thanks, that was the tidbit I needed to clear all my confusion up. If you want to post it as an 'answer' I'll be happy to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer stems from a simple point with big ramifications - a makefile has two dialects, 1) the make language itself and 2) the shell language you use for stuff like invoking `gcc`.

A reminder of the normal make "rule" syntax:

```
targets : prerequisites
        recipe
```

While the make target and prerequisites is in make
syntax, the stuff in the recipe is *in the shell syntax, not make syntax*.

This explains why you cannot do stuff like assign make variables as part of a recipe, as so:

```
all: the_dependencies_of_all
    this_will_not_work := because_the_shell_does_not_know_what_this_line_means
```

In the shell syntax bits, make does three special text manipulations, and then the remaining string is passed verbatim to the shell. The three steps are

1. deal with escaped newlines (e.g. backslash followed by newline)
2. run any make functions (like `$(filter ....)` and `$(eval ..)`
3. expand any make target variables (like `$@`)

In the normal case, this 3-steps-then-shell processs happens once per recipe line, so each line of your makefile recipe is run in a different shell (hence why some calls to `make` will spawns many `/bin/sh` sub-processes).

Manipulation #2 above explains why you can use `eval` inside a recipe to add some make syntax to your recipe. Eval will turn into an empty string, which will cause no problems with the shell, but make will have evaluated the string inside your statement, so stuff like variable definitions is possible.

The precise moment this evaluation happens is a bit tricky to pin down - it seems to happen when the variable is first expanded, which itself depends upon where you reference that variable in your makefile. Perhaps someone can clarify this a bit more, since when this happens has been ramifications for invocations of make that use the `-j` flag to run multiple recipe lines in parallel

More Info:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Introduction.html#Rule-Introduction
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipe-Syntax.html#Recipe-Syntax
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Splitting-Recipe-Lines.html#Splitting-Recipe-Lines